# What does “|” mean?

Tags: symfony, twig

i want to know what this symbol | mean and when we use it

```
{{ entity.date|date('d-m-Y')}
```

Could someone explain it for me?

Comment: You know that your are using symfony and twig. I suggest you first read the [documentation for twig](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#filters) before going any further in your developement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called [a filter](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/templates.html#filters). It applies a filter to a variable or expression to the left. For example

```
{{ name|striptags }}
```

will apply a striptags filter to a name variable.

In your case a date formatting filter is applied, to make the date look according to a certain format.

The full list of builtin filters can be found [here](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/index.html).

Filters can be chained, for example

```
{{ name|striptags|title }}
```

will apply a striptags filter to a name variable and then apply a title filter to the resulting value.